# How to get the permission of `/run/user/1000/gvfs` when system is newly installed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, permissions, bash

System is newly installed debian 10.
I cannot get the permission of `/run/user/1000/gvfs` properly,changed from `d?????????  ? ?     ?       ?            ?` to `dr-x------` when `cd /run/user/1000`.

```
me@pc:~$ sudo ls -al /run/user/1000
[sudo] password for me: 
ls: cannot access '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
total 0
drwx------ 11 me me 280 Jul 22 14:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root   60 Jul 22 02:07 ..
srw-rw-rw-  1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 bus
drwx------  3 me me  60 Jul 22 02:06 dbus-1
drwx------  2 me me  60 Jul 22 14:53 dconf
drwx------  3 me me  60 Jul 22 02:06 gnome-shell
drwx------  2 me me 140 Jul 22 02:06 gnupg
d?????????  ? ?     ?       ?            ? gvfs
drwx------  2 me me  40 Jul 22 02:12 gvfs-burn
drwx------  2 me me 100 Jul 22 02:06 keyring
drwx------  2 me me  80 Jul 22 02:06 pulse
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me  80 Jul 22 02:06 systemd
srwxr-xr-x  1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 wayland-0
-rw-r-----  1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 wayland-0.lock
me@pc:~$ cd /run/user/1000
me@pc:/run/user/1000$ find * -print0 | xargs -0 ls -al
srw-rw-rw- 1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 bus
-rw------- 1 me me   2 Jul 22 14:58 dconf/user
srw------- 1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 gnupg/S.dirmngr
srw------- 1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 gnupg/S.gpg-agent
srw------- 1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser
srw------- 1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
srw------- 1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
srwxr-xr-x 1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 keyring/control
srwxr-xr-x 1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 keyring/pkcs11
srwxr-xr-x 1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 keyring/ssh
srw-rw-rw- 1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 pulse/native
-rw------- 1 me me   5 Jul 22 02:06 pulse/pid
srwxr-xr-x 1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 systemd/notify
srwxr-xr-x 1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 systemd/private
srwxr-xr-x 1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 wayland-0
-rw-r----- 1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 wayland-0.lock

dbus-1:
total 0
drwx------  3 me me  60 Jul 22 02:06 .
drwx------ 11 me me 280 Jul 22 14:58 ..
drwx------  2 me me  40 Jul 22 02:06 services

dbus-1/services:
total 0
drwx------ 2 me me 40 Jul 22 02:06 .
drwx------ 3 me me 60 Jul 22 02:06 ..

dconf:
total 4
drwx------  2 me me  60 Jul 22 14:56 .
drwx------ 11 me me 280 Jul 22 14:58 ..
-rw-------  1 me me   2 Jul 22 14:58 user

gnome-shell:
total 0
drwx------  3 me me  60 Jul 22 02:06 .
drwx------ 11 me me 280 Jul 22 14:58 ..
drwx------  2 me me  40 Jul 22 02:06 runtime-state-LE.:0

'gnome-shell/runtime-state-LE.:0':
total 0
drwx------ 2 me me 40 Jul 22 02:06 .
drwx------ 3 me me 60 Jul 22 02:06 ..

gnupg:
total 0
drwx------  2 me me 140 Jul 22 02:06 .
drwx------ 11 me me 280 Jul 22 14:58 ..
srw-------  1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 S.dirmngr
srw-------  1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 S.gpg-agent
srw-------  1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 S.gpg-agent.browser
srw-------  1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 S.gpg-agent.extra
srw-------  1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 S.gpg-agent.ssh

gvfs:
total 0
dr-x------  2 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 .
drwx------ 11 me me 280 Jul 22 14:58 ..
me@pc:/run/user/1000$ ls -al
total 0
drwx------ 11 me me 280 Jul 22 14:58 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root   60 Jul 22 02:07 ..
srw-rw-rw-  1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 bus
drwx------  3 me me  60 Jul 22 02:06 dbus-1
drwx------  2 me me  60 Jul 22 14:56 dconf
drwx------  3 me me  60 Jul 22 02:06 gnome-shell
drwx------  2 me me 140 Jul 22 02:06 gnupg
dr-x------  2 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 gvfs
drwx------  2 me me  40 Jul 22 02:12 gvfs-burn
drwx------  2 me me 100 Jul 22 02:06 keyring
drwx------  2 me me  80 Jul 22 02:06 pulse
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me  80 Jul 22 02:06 systemd
srwxr-xr-x  1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 wayland-0
-rw-r-----  1 me me   0 Jul 22 02:06 wayland-0.lock
```

How to  get the permission of `/run/user/1000/gvfs` when system is newly installed?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to make changes to the gvfs daemon to allow the root user to access the '/run/user/1000/gvfs' directory, as it can cause security and data integrity issues. However, if you still want to do it for testing purposes on an old computer you do not care whether computer and operating system stop working, then for the sake of breaking it Here YOU GO:

First need to configure th gvfs daemon configuration to allow user access:
1.Edit the gvfsd.conf file located in the /etc/gvfs/ directory. This file
contains the configuration settings for the gvfs daemon.

Locate the line that starts with "#user" and remove the "#" character. This will enable the user configuration settings.

Add a new line with the user "root" to the file, this way:

#user
to-->
*user root*

Save the changes and restart the gvfs daemon. On most systems, this can be done by running the following command:

*sudo systemctl restart gvfs-daemon*

You should now be able to access the '/run/user/1000/gvfs' directory as the root user.
However, as mentioned before this is NOT RECOMMENDED, there is a reason why access is only for the gvfs. It's not a good practice, especially in a.. anywhere and mostly .. NEVER EVER.. It's always better to leave this as it is.
as they say:
"Hack the planet!"
If this work put a comment here with you other computer/laptop you did not F*ck up
-chears-